# add specific word every new line

Tags: mysql, sql, phpdesigner

Hi guys i want to add specific word on the beginning of every new line of a block of code like this block of SQL code which i exported from phpmyadmin 
lets say i wand add the word "ADD" on every new line
how to achieve that by the editor like 'phpdesigner' or 'netbeans' instead of add the word manually by copy and paste every line

```
  `Sinus_Rhythm` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sinus_Tachycardia` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cardiac_Arrhythmia` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cardiac_Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Right_Heart_Strain` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Other_Abnormality` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LVF` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `RVF` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAPs` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pericardial_Effusion` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Diastolic_Dysfunction` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `RWMA` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Echo_Other` enum('Yes','No') DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: use a text editor like notepad++ and replace `\n` with `\nAND `

Comment: worked with netbeans but didnt with PHPDesigner
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use netbeans, you can just 'Find/Replace', enable regular expressions, find `^` (start of line) and replace with `ADD`? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your file with vim and do a simple:

`s,^,ADD ,`

and remove the ADD on the first line. That would do the trick.

Otherwise, see if your editor doesn't have a regex replace function: make it replace `^` with `ADD`, remove the first and you're equally set.